# Submit generated value to input Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a form in which an input in that form auto-generates a unique `group_id`. I set the value of that input to the randomly-generated string and set the input field to disabled so they can not edit it unless they click a check-box.

When I submit the form however the value does not go into the database even though I have the `:group_id` set in the permit params.

```
<%= form.text_field :group_id, id: :group_id, class: 'form-control inline', value: "DSC-" + "#{@pdnum.id}".rjust(3, '0').to_s, disabled: true %>
```

Does the value not get submitted into the database? If not, how can I get around this so that this randomly generated string is placed into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `readonly: true` instead of `disabled`